# azure repo branch policies

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I've spent the afternoon tidying up some repos in azure devops. All is going well.

One question i can not get an answer to is limiting / protecting branches. I'm working with an existing project with work flow branches:

{new features}->nightly->test->master

Currently this is done manually and there are stories of tired developers on a Friday afternoon rushing and ballsing up the flow and killing production (master branch)

I've put in place a number of policies for example number of reviewers and validation by running  unit tests.

The question is, with Azure repos can i limit what branch can be PR'ed into another and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution if anyone finds this....
Use conditionals and "if"

`condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables.sourceBranch)`

Answer (score 0):

Project >> Settings >> Repositories >> Select Repo >> Policies >> Select Branch

You can't control whether it can be PR'd into, only the hoops that people need to jump through before it can be approved and/or merged

- Min # reviewers
- Check for linked work items
- Check for comment resolution
- **Limit Merge Types**:  Maybe turn this on and uncheck *all* the boxes, so that when a PR is approved it can't be merged?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, with Azure repos can i limit what branch can be PR'ed into another and how?

I am afraid there is no such a out of box branch policies that you could limit what branch can be PR'ed into another.

**As workaround**, we could add a task in the build validation pipeline to failed the pipeline if the branch which triggered build validation is not the branch we expected, we setup the build fails. This way others will not be able to merge the unexpected branch into the target branch.

As test, I created a Inline powershell task to limit what branch can be PR'ed into:

```
$branch = $Env:System_PullRequest_SourceBranch
Write-Host "Current branch is $branch"
if ($branch -eq "refs/heads/Dev1")
{
  Write-Host ("The source branch is expected branch.")
}
elseif ($branch -ne "refs/heads/Dev1")
{
  Write-Host ("##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]DONE")
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that Leo Liu-MSFT. My solution was to use jobs->job in the yaml pipeline with a condition looking at the source branch.

```
condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables.sourceBranch)
```